# Custom Error Message for Event Receiver in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, event-receiver

I want users to upload the .doc files only in the document library.

To do so, I have developed an event receiver in Visual Studio 2010.

My code is as follows:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
       try
       {

           base.ItemAdding(properties);
           EventFiringEnabled = false;

           if (!properties.AfterUrl.EndsWith("doc"))
           {
               properties.ErrorMessage = "You are allowed to updload only .doc files";
               properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
               properties.Cancel = true;

           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
           properties.ErrorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
           properties.Cancel = true;
       }

}
```

The code is referred from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventproperties.aspx) example.

My problem is that while I am uploading non-doc files it is preventing but with the system error message not the user friendly as defined in `properties.ErrorMessage`.

How do I solve this?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the same code you have provided in your question, I get custom error message displayed as shown in below image -

[image]

Please provide details of the error you are getting.

Comment: Open your web.config file ["C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\YourAppPort\web.config"] and set CustomError = "On" and then check.

Comment: Set CallStack="false" in web.config file; give it a try.

Comment: Created new solution and rewrote the code but still the same error occurs... @Amit Thakkar

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your solution, try setting CallStack="false" in web.config file; this should work. But make sure you are applying web.config changes to your application's web.config file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34070/discussion-between-riyaz-kalva-and-amit-thakkar)